# Could not load requested class : jcache

Tags: hibernate, gradle, jcache

I am trying to run a gradle project. the build is working correctly but whe I launch **gradle run** I get this error

```
org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [jcache]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:152)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : jcache
```

and here are the dependencies in my gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    runtime "com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre"
    runtime "com.opencsv:opencsv:3.9"
    runtime "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.14.0"
    runtime "org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.25"

    runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.0.0"
    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.41"

    runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final"
    runtime  "org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.2.10.Final"
    runtime  "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.1.Final"
    runtime  "org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache:5.2.10.Final"    
    runtime 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'    
    
    runtime 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.6.8.Final'
    runtime 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.5.2.Final'
    runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.7.0.Final"
    runtime 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.

}
```

I am suspecting an issue with the hibernate libraries versions.

Comment: Any reason to use this wild variety  of hibernate versions? Also, if you suspect the version to be the problem, why don't you try that before asking here?

Comment: I tried many versions already. none worked fine for me.
I am not sure about the version that I should use so I posted on stackoverflow

Comment: Well, definitely not 5 different ones. Decide on 1 hibernate version and use it for all dependencies. Also it seems that `jcache` is the successor of `ehcache`. So why use both?

Answer (score 0):

this combination of versions worked for me

```
    runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.1.Final"
    runtime  "org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.6.1.Final"
    runtime  "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.4.1.Final"
    runtime 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jcache:5.6.1.Final'
```